# Transit visa for Filipino at Narita?

Tags: transit, filipino-citizens, nrt

I have a Philippine passport. I'm traveling from Guam to LAX (have a US tourist visa) and returning Houston to Guam. Both flights stopover in Narita, for 4 hours and 8 hours. Do I need a transit visa?

Thanks!